Can tendons also "pop" noisily?
I understand that synovial fluid lubricating each joint and each tendon to prevent reaps or tears, is biosynthesized in membranes wrapping each joint and each tendon.
In various rapid movements of a joint, especially when the joint is inflamed, nitrogen gas can be released out of the synovial fluid of a joint, what's known as "popping joints", that is noisy alright.
But when a tendon moves, especially when tendinitis or tendosynovitis occur, can there be similar noise?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
